# How to add footer link in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, footer-links, custom-theme

I have created block title **Footer Links Block** and block identifier **footer_links_block** and added bellow code into block.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-9 pad_right">
<div class="qucik_link">
<div class="sitemap">
<ul class="footer_link">
<li><a> Quick Links</a>
<ul>
<li><a title="About Us" href="{{store url="about-als"}}" target="_self">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url="become-a-carepartner"}}">Become a Care Partner</a></li>
<li><a title="Article" href="{{store url="article"}}" target="_self">Knowledge Centre</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url="latest-offers"}}">Latest Offers</a></li>
<li><a title="News &amp; Article" href="{{store url="news"}}" target="_self">News &amp; Articles</a></li>
<li><a title="FAQ" href="{{store url="faq"}}" target="_self">FAQs</a></li>
{{block class="Als\ThemeExt\Block\TrackLink" template="Als_ThemeExt::tracklink.phtml"}}
<li><a href="{{store url="contact-us"}}">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="sitemap">
<ul class="footer_link">
<li><a> Shop by</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="{{store url="ruminants.html"}}">Ruminants</a></li>
<li><a href=" {{store url="Pets.html"}}">Pets</a></li>
<li><a href=" {{store url="equines.html"}}">Equines</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="sitemap">
<ul class="footer_link">
<li><a> Our Policies</a>
<ul>
<li><a href=" {{store url="terms-and-conditions"}}">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
<li><a href=" {{store url="privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode"}}">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li><a href=" {{store url="shipping-returns-cancellation"}}">Shipment</a></li>
<li><a href=" {{store url="order-cancellation"}}">Order Cancellation</a></li>
<li><a href=" {{store url="replacement"}}">Replacement</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url="disclaimer"}}">Disclaimer</a></li>
<li><a href="http://amaruventures.co.in/demo1/als_demo/compliance">Compliance</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="sitemap">
<h3>Call us for any assitance <strong>1800-212-5500</strong></h3>
<div class="social_icon">
<h3>Follow us on</h3>
<ul>
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/alsvetcarecom-321977024847350 "><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.twiter.com/alsvetcare/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/alsvetcare.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/alsvetcare/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/+alsvetcare"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="shipping_data">
<ul>
<li><span><i class="fa fa-inr"></i></span> Cash on Delivery*</li>
<li><span><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></span> 3 Days Return*</li>
<li><span><i class="fa fa-truck"></i></span> Free Shipping*</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

after that add fallowing code in `app\design\frontend\Magenticians\Mytheme\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <container name="footer-top" label="Footer Top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="quick_bg" before="-">
    <container name="footer-top-container" label="Footer Top Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container" before="-">
    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_links_block">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_links_block</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    </container>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

after that ran all CLI command. but its not working for me.

Comment: Try with <referenceContainer name="footer"> instead of <referenceContainer name="footer-container">

Comment: `php bin/magento cache:clean` try this and check it.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
  <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true" />
```

**1.** Add Above Code in

> app\design\frontend\Magenticians\Mytheme\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml

**2. Go to Content > Widgets > Add Widget**

a. Select Type > CMS Static Block | Desgin Theme > Your Theme => Click Continue

b. See "Layout Updates" Tab in Storefront Properties:

```
      i. Display On : All Pages
     ii. Container : CMS Footer Links
```

c. Go to Widget Option and select your Block.

Comment: I fallowed above state but i did not get anything.

Comment: Have you added this in your custom theme default.xml :                               <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true" />

Comment: yes i have added above code in my default.xml...

Comment: after added above code in deafult.xml i am getting this on footer link "We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email." and copyright

Answer (score 0):

Now try this.

> app\design\frontend\Magenticians\Mytheme\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml

```
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <container name="footer.top" label="footer top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-top">
            <container name="footer.top.container" label="footer top Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
                <container name="top.left.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-12">     
                    <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe" as="subscribe" before="-" template="subscribe.phtml"/>
                </container>
            </container>
        </container>
         <container name="footer.static" label="footer static" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-static">
            <container name="footer.static.container" label="footer static Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_static">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_static</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </container> 
        <container name="footer.copyright" label="footer copyright" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-copyright">
            <container name="footer.copyright.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
                <container name="copyright.left.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">   
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="my-copyright" template="html/copyright.phtml"/>
                </container>
                <container name="copyright.right.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_payment">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_payment</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
            </container>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: still not working for me.

Comment: update code in my theme default.xml file so it will help you

Comment: <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header_social1">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_social</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>

Comment: what is header_social1 and header social can you explain

Comment: my theme functionality etc.

Comment: theme functionality? i have mentioned block identifier name where have you added header_social1

Comment: actual what issue you are facing right now.

Comment: i am not getting footer link. i dont know how to add block in footer link. <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_static"> name should be block identifier name and <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_static</argument> here block title name or anything else

Comment: please share default.xml file code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70890/discussion-between-ravindrasinh-zala-and-er-sarvesh-v-tiwari).

Comment: <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <container name="footer.top" label="Footer Top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="quick_bg" before="-">
        <container name="als footer.top.container" label="Als Footer Top Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container" before="-"> 
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_links_block">
     <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_links_block</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
     </container>
    </container>
</referenceCont>